# Showing -webkit-transition using jQuery css

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

I am using jQuery for styling

```
$('#content').css({'width': '10%', '-webkit-transition': '1s all'});
```

How can I make the `-webkit-transition` work using jQuery css

Comment: Are you trying to target only Webkit based browsers? Which one are you using? You'll also need to make sure to set the original width of #content so it knows what to transition from.

Comment: $('#content').animate({
    width: "10%"
});

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) :

> Formal syntax: [ none | `<single-transition-property>` ] || `<time>` ||
>   `<timing-function>` || `<time>`
>
> Note that order is important within the items in this property: the
>   first value that can be parsed as a time is assigned to the
>   `transition-duration`, and the second value that can be parsed as a time
>   is assigned to `transition-delay`.

So your syntax is wrong, it should be `all 1s` but am not sure why you are doing that with jQuery when you can achieve that with pure CSS.

```
$('#content').css({'width': '10%', '-webkit-transition': 'all 1s'});
                                                        ---^---
```

Developers use jQuery to fill the gap of cross browsers issue, here you are using browser specific property, and that too with jQuery, doesn't make sense.

If you want to do with pure CSS, use

```
#content {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```